# Microsoft Bot Framework mixing conversation and dialogs between users who send request to bot at same time

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, state, chatbot

I have implemented a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework SDK 4. The Bot is working fine, however I have experienced its not working when two users sends the request to the bot at same time.

I have printed the turnContext values for the users on each turn and its printing correct user and conversation data, however when the beginDialog calls, then sometimes its encountered with Error or sometimes it's mixing dialog response to users (Bot send response to other user).

I have implemented multiple dialogs steps using Waterfall Dialog: Find below code snippet : Where Message 'Hi there :) Welcome User : Name of the user ' is working fine with multiple users, but beginDialog is not working and mixing response to users.

In bot.ts

```js
adapter.onMessage = async turnContext => {
    const results = await adapter.continueDialog()
    const recognitionResult = await Luis.recognize(turnContext)
    const { topScoringIntent } = recognitionResult
    
    if (topScoringIntent === 'welcome') {
        await turnContext.sendActivity(`Hi there :) Welcome User ${turnContext.activity.form.name}` )
        await adapter.beginDialog(DialogsTimebot.GreetingDialog, {
                recognitionResult
        })
    }
}
```

In adapter.ts

```js
async beginDialog(dialog: Dialog, options: object | undefined) {
    if (!dialogMap.has(dialog)) {
        const id = `dialog-${randomId()}`
        const dialogClass = new (class extends ComponentDialog {
          constructor() {
            super(id)
            this.addDialog(
              new WaterfallDialog(
                `waterfall-${id}`,
                dialog.steps.map(step => modStep(step, dialogMap))
              )
            )
          }
        })()
        dialogMap.set(dialog, { id, dialogClass })
        _dialogSet.add(dialogClass)
    }
    const dialogId = dialogMap.get(dialog)!.id
    await _dialogContext.beginDialog(dialogId, options)
},
```

Can anyone please help how to solve this issue? I have got stuck and not able to find the root cause. Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello @Kyle Delaney, Issue is my bot is sending dialog to other user when multiple users are accessing bot at same time. Sometimes there is an error "TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked"

Comment: Okay. What is your question?

Comment: Hello @Kelly, I have updated the question. I need help to solve this issue.

Comment: Your bot code is unlike any I've seen. Can you provide some links so we know why you're building a bot that way? It would also help to see more of your bot code. It doesn't make a lot of sense to have a `beginDialog` function in your adapter, but it especially doesn't make sense to not even pass the turn context to it. Where is the dialog context coming from? You should have a look at the samples to get a better idea of how bots are supposed to work: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs

Comment: Are you still working on this?